# K-derivations and Lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, lie-algebras

I had a question regarding a statement that was on the Wikipedia page for Derivations. It states that $\text{Der}_k(A)$ is a Lie algebra with the Lie bracket being the commutator. Here $\text{Der}_k(A)$ is the $K$-module consisting of $K$ linear mappings $D: A \rightarrow A$ that satisfies the Leibniz rule. Also, here $A$ is a commutative $K$-algebra.

If I wanted to show this for my self, would I just need to show that $[ \cdot , \cdot]$ is a bilinear mapping that is skew symmetric and satisfies the Jacobi identity?

For instance for skew symmetry, would it be as simple as taking a derivation $D \in \text{Der}_k(A)$ and stating that $[D,D] = DD - DD = 0?

Also, would I have to show that the commutator of 2 derivations is a derivation? If so, I'm not sure how to conclude that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, obviously $[D,D]=DD-DD=0$ is satisfied. For the Leibniz rule, we have for all $x,y\in A$,
\begin{align*}
[D_1,D_2](x\cdot y) & = (D_1D_2)(x\cdot y)-(D_2D_1)(x\cdot y)\\
 & = D_1(D_2(x)\cdot y+x\cdot D_2(y))-  D_2(D_1(x)\cdot y+x\cdot D_1(y))\\
 & = (D_1D_2(x))\cdot y +x\cdot (D_1D_2(y)))+D_2(x)\cdot D_1(y) + D_1(x)\cdot D_2(y)\\
 & - (D_2D_1(x))\cdot y-x\cdot (D_2D_1(y))-D_1(x)\cdot D_2(y)-D_2(x)\cdot D_1(y) \\
 & = [D_1,D_2](x)\cdot y+x\cdot [D_1,D_2](y).
\end{align*}

Here we have added and subtracted the terms $D_1(x)\cdot D_2(y)$ and $D_2(x)\cdot D_1(y)$.

So we have shown that for $D_1,D_2 \in {\rm Der}(A)$ we have $[D_1,D_2]\in {\rm Der}(A)$, so that ${\rm Der}(A)$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(A)$. Moreover we haven't used that $A$ is commutative, or associative.

Comment: That makes complete sense.

Comment: What about the Jacobi Identity?

Comment: As a Lie subalgebra of a linear Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(A)$, the Jacobi identity is automatically satisfied.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to prove that [.,] satisfices the Jacobi identity by definition?

Comment: As I said, linear Lie algebras have the Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$, which always satisfies the Jacobi identity.